# Java: making basic controls

Tags: java

I am going to get into GUI soon and I wanted to know a way to enable a java program to detect if a user presses a key on the keyboard by using ActionListener, then determining what to do depending on what key the user pressed. I have heard of variables called *char* variables that can hold a letter and I was also wondering if these have some involvement in testing user input.

If using ActionListener to detect user input is unnecessary, please explain to me in the simplest way how programmers usually make games that have the classic W A S D controls and stuff like that.

Comment: You might want to look into [Key Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) or [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyListener` is the interface you're looking for. Create a class implementing `KeyListener`, then call `addKeyListener(...)` on your window (a class extending `JFrame`). Specifically, the method `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)` can be used to respond to keyboard button pushes.

To elaborate, `ActionListeners` are specifically for handling the firing of various "Actions". As it pertains to you, that means the clicking of `JButton`s or `JMenuItem`s. `ActionListener`s won't catch keyboard presses or other mouse movement such as dragging.

Here's a bit of a class I wrote for a game I'm working on to handle keyboard input. It uses the arrow keys for movement, the Z key as the `A`button and the X key as the `B` button (think traditional emulator setup).

```
/** Manager for all keyboard input. Only singleton instance is allowed. */
public class KeyboardListener implements KeyListener{

    /** The up key code */
    public static final int UP = KeyEvent.VK_UP;
    /** The left key code */
    public static final int LEFT = KeyEvent.VK_LEFT;
    /** The down key code */
    public static final int DOWN = KeyEvent.VK_DOWN;
    /** The right key code */
    public static final int RIGHT = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT;
    /** The "a" (main button / weak confirm button) key code */
    public static final int A = KeyEvent.VK_Z;
    /** The "b" (secondary button / weak decline button) key code */
    public static final int B = KeyEvent.VK_X;
    /** The "start" (tertiary / strong confirm button) key code */
    public static final int START = KeyEvent.VK_ENTER;
    /** The "esc" (tertiary / strong decline button) key code */
    public static final int ESC = KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE;

    /** The singleton instance of keyboardListener to be used by all frames */
    protected static final KeyboardListener instance = new KeyboardListener();

    /** Constructor for KeyboardListener */
    private KeyboardListener(){}

    /** The frame this KeyboardListener is listening to */
    private Frame frame; //Note - Frame is a class I've written, Frame extends JFrame

    /** Set the Frame the KeyboardListener is listening to */
    public static void setFrame(Frame f){
        instance.frame = f;
        instance.frame.addKeyListener(instance);
    }

    /** Unused */
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    /** Handle key presses */
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { 
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == UP){
          //Handle push of the up arrow
        }
        //etc....
    }

    /** Unused */
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {};
}
```

Comment: okay, my only worry is that I also need to implement ActionListener for menus and buttons, how would I implement both simultaneously?

Comment: If you are talking about the GUI component that goes on the top of a window (a `JMenu`), then yeah you want actionListeners on your `JMenuItem`s so that they handle mouse clicks. If you want that, that's another question directly about actionListeners.

Comment: @pebble225 Use the `Action` API, this allows you to define a single action which can be applied to a key binding, `JButton`, `JMenu` and `JMenuItem` which provides a centralised configuration point (the `Action`) for all these elements

Comment: Okay, I tried doing this, but can you help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ifwmve7n6ly52h/g.txt?dl=0

Comment: You never actually call `setFrame(...)`. Add `event.setFrame(main)` to your main method.

Comment: Thanks man! Here is me in this situation: https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQY7v4Y6IP2j8Ugl0Gy4y2Uz3h9WpAE9_KOe6FlxbcGQcaVE46h

Answer (score 1):

When you have a predefined set of key inputs, one of the simplest solutions is to use the Key Bindings API. See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details.

`JButton`, `JMenu` and `JMenuItem` allow you to provide key board short-cuts.

See:

- [`JButton#setMnemonic(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMnemonic(int))
- [`JMenuItem#setAccelerator(KeyStroke)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke))
- [`JMenu#setAccelerator(KeyStroke)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke))

For more details.

You may also want to take a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), which allows you to define a centralised action object which can be applied to key bindings, buttons and menus, making it easy to implemented re-usable actions